# how to list the last n patches added to a repo in git?

Tags: git

I have a callback in my code which I use to refresh my 3d webgl scene. I have inserted this at various places in my code. My cpu usage is > 100% after my latest commit even when my webgl scene id idle. How do I cat a list of last n patches I have added to my repo. I want to grep through this list to find all the new callbacks I have added.

Comment: Will git log give you what you need? http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Answer (score 0):

```
git show HEAD~10..HEAD
```

And you can obviously pipe this into `grep` or whatever you need:

```
git show HEAD~10..HEAD | grep MyCallback
```

Comment: great that does the trick, but how do I know which file and in which line these changes are? after doing git show HEAD~10..HEAD | grep MyCallback

Comment: perhaps an easier approach would be to use `git log -p` and just search for callbacks. This way, you'll also have the surrounding context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used `git bisect`?

It might help you in locating the specific patch that causes the bug.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search

It does a Binary Search between your current bad commit, and a known good commit in the past.

You start it off, mark the current commit as bad and then indicate a commit id for a known good commit.

```
$ git bisect start
$ git bisect bad
$ git bisect good <commit-id/branch name/tag>
```

Git will then find a halfway point between the two commits and check out that code, you can run your test manually and indicate if this particular commit is good or bad.

If Good:

```
$ git bisect good
```

If Bad:

```
$ git bisect bad
```

Git will continue presenting you with commits until it narrows it down to a likely commit and will show you a commit-id and list of changed files.

When you are done, to go back to your initial state:

```
$ git bisect reset
```

And if the test you perform at every checkout can be automated you can pass it to bisect to run the bisect automatically.

```
$ git bisect start <BAD commit id> <GOOD commit id>
$ git bisect run <script OR command with 0 exit if good>
```

Example:

```
$ git bisect start HEAD v1.0
$ git bisect run test-error.sh
OR
$ git bisect run make test
```